# Get "0 pods were found" in cocoapods version 1.0.0.rc.2

Tags: ios, cocoapods

i installed cocoapods by running this command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

But when i run command

```
pod list
```

I got "0 pods were found" 
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: do you get the following instruction from terminal `13 gems installed`

Comment: No i get only 1 gem installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first need to install CocoaPods. CocoaPods runs on Ruby

Fortunately, all recent versions of Mac OS X (since OS X 10.7 Lion) ship with Ruby already installed. So all you need to do is update RubyGems

To do so, open Terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Next, you need to install CocoaPods. Type this command in Terminal to do so:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Lastly, enter this command in Terminal to complete the setup of CocoaPods: pod setup

Open Terminal and navigate to the directory containing your project by using the cd command:

```
cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/yourProject
```

Next enter this command: pod init

This will create a default Podfile for your project. The Podfile is where you define the dependencies your project relies on. Type this command to open Podfile using Xcode for editing:

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

`platform :ios, '7.0' pod 'apptentive-ios'`// write framework which you want to use in cocopods

Save and close the pod file. You now need to tell CocoaPods to “install” the dependencies for your project. Enter the following command in Terminal to do so (making sure that you’re still in the directory containing the ShowTracker project and Podfile):

```
 pod install
```

VERY IMPORTANT! From now on, as the command-line warning mentioned, you must always open the workspace (ShowTracker.xcworkspace) and not the project! Now You need to add two more dependencies for this project. Rather than opening PodFile from the command line, you can now find it in the Pods target in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the installed successfully message from terminal?

> Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.0.0.rc.2.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   cocoapods-core-1.0.0.rc.2 Fetching: claide-1.0.0.rc.1.gem (100%)
>   Successfully installed claide-1.0.0.rc.1 Fetching:
>   cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.0.rc.2.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.0.rc.2 Fetching:
>   cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0.rc.1.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0.rc.1 Fetching:
>   cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.rc.1.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.rc.1 Fetching: cocoapods-search-1.0.0.rc.1.gem
>   (100%) Successfully installed cocoapods-search-1.0.0.rc.1 Fetching:
>   cocoapods-stats-1.0.0.rc.1.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   cocoapods-stats-1.0.0.rc.1 Fetching: cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0.rc.1.gem
>   (100%) Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0.rc.1 Fetching:
>   cocoapods-try-1.0.0.rc.1.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   cocoapods-try-1.0.0.rc.1 Fetching: molinillo-0.4.5.gem (100%)
>   Successfully installed molinillo-0.4.5 Fetching:
>   xcodeproj-1.0.0.rc.2.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   xcodeproj-1.0.0.rc.2 Fetching: fourflusher-0.3.0.gem (100%)
>   Successfully installed fourflusher-0.3.0 Fetching:
>   cocoapods-1.0.0.rc.2.gem (100%) Successfully installed
>   cocoapods-1.0.0.rc.2 Parsing documentation for
>   cocoapods-core-1.0.0.rc.2 Installing ri documentation for
>   cocoapods-core-1.0.0.rc.2 Parsing documentation for claide-1.0.0.rc.1
>   Installing ri documentation for claide-1.0.0.rc.1 Parsing
>   documentation for cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.0.rc.2 Installing ri
>   documentation for cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.0.rc.2 Parsing
>   documentation for cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0.rc.1 Installing ri
>   documentation for cocoapods-downloader-1.0.0.rc.1 Parsing
>   documentation for cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.rc.1 Installing ri
>   documentation for cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.rc.1 Parsing documentation
>   for cocoapods-search-1.0.0.rc.1 Installing ri documentation for
>   cocoapods-search-1.0.0.rc.1 Parsing documentation for
>   cocoapods-stats-1.0.0.rc.1 Installing ri documentation for
>   cocoapods-stats-1.0.0.rc.1 Parsing documentation for
>   cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0.rc.1 Installing ri documentation for
>   cocoapods-trunk-1.0.0.rc.1 Parsing documentation for
>   cocoapods-try-1.0.0.rc.1 Installing ri documentation for
>   cocoapods-try-1.0.0.rc.1 Parsing documentation for molinillo-0.4.5
>   Installing ri documentation for molinillo-0.4.5 Parsing documentation
>   for xcodeproj-1.0.0.rc.2 Installing ri documentation for
>   xcodeproj-1.0.0.rc.2 Parsing documentation for fourflusher-0.3.0
>   Installing ri documentation for fourflusher-0.3.0 Parsing
>   documentation for cocoapods-1.0.0.rc.2 Installing ri documentation for
>   cocoapods-1.0.0.rc.2 13 gems installed

Comment: No after installation i got only 1 gem installed